# count all pair of vertex with constraints in an undirected graph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

I'm struggling the following an algorithmic puzzle:

given a graph with N vertex and N edges I've to count all pairs of vertex (A,B) with the following properties: A>B and exists at least one path made of all vertex labeled with numbers between A and B...

As example (1,5) is a valid pair of vertex if the following path exists: (1,2,3,4,5) but would be ok even if the following would exists (1,5,2,3,4) or (1,3,4,3,2,3,5)... I'm not interested in the length of the path or its order it just have to include all vertex which label is >= A and <= B. I've tried with modified bfs and dfs but had no success.

can some one help?

give some hint?

thanks

Comment: What are the constraints ?

Comment: Hi, the graph have exactly N nodes and N edges. edges from A->A can exists. we are sure the graph is connected. lets say it cannot have more than 10000 nodes. nodes are labeled from 0 to N-1.  hope you can give some hint. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete all edges which are connecting two nodes with not consecutive numbers. (e.g. a edge connecting node 2 with node 6, but not a edge from node 2 to node 3). In the modified graph, each node has either degree 0, 1 or 2.

Now traverse the graph starting at node 1. Store all visited nodes in a list. If you reach a node with degree 1, start again on node 2. (and then on node 3 and so on).

Consider the following example output for a graph with 7 nodes and edges E={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{6,7}}. Please note that 1..5 denotes a list with the following elements {1},{2},{3},{4},{5}.

node | list | valid pairs

1    | 1..5 | 4 {(1,5),(1,4),(1,3),(1,2)}

2    | 2..5 | 3 {(2,5),{2,4),(2,3)}

3    | 3..5 | 2

4    | 4..5 | 1

5    | 5..5 | 0

6    | 6..7 | 1

7    | 7..7 | 0

This should answer your question. Sorry for the bad formatting of the table. As you can see in the table, you can calculate the valid pairs for node 2,3,4 and 5 once you have all pairs for node 1. So there is some space to improve my algorithm.

Comment: hi Lho, thanks for your answer.
the problem is more subtle and I've not explained it properly. the original graph should be connected so at least an edge {1,6} had to exist. then a valid pair is (1,6) with the following path: {1,6,1,2,3,4,5}. and (1,7) with path {1,6,7,6,1,2,3,4,5}
(2,6) is not valid because in the path node 1 must be included violating one constraint

Comment: There are  still open questions, but there is a more urgent one. You are writing, that the original graph is "connected so at least an edge {1,6} exists". You also wrote in an earlier comment, that your graph has n nodes and n edges. So your graph is a tree with one single additional edge?

Comment: is better to say that it has at most N edges and it's connected.it could be a tree. lets take this series of edges (1,2) (2,3) (1,3) this is not a tree. while this is a tree (1,2) (3,2) (4,2) (5,2) (6,2) .and remember that it's undirected